# Linux driver for mmap

Tags: linux, arm, mmap, virtual-memory

I am new to linux drivers and I wanted to map the virtual address in the linux side to physical address and my target platform is ARM. What are different ways to map set of virtual addresses into physical addresses.
My aim is to write values into specific address in physical memory continuously.

For example: If I map addresses 0x000FF000 to 0x00FFFFFF to physical space then I will be writing values to 0x000FF000 continuously and the target connected to that  address receives that values.

And this mapping should happen during initial boot up time so that I can write into that address any time after that just by using the pointer address returned by say mmap function.

Do I need to write device driver for this?
or is it possible to achieve this by doing  mmap like this,

```
fd=open(/dev/mem,O_RDWR);
start_ptr = mmap(NULL, MEMORY_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
```

If I write a device driver for this then how do I pass offset address returned by the mmap to user space?

Comment: _"is it possible to achieve this by doing mmap like this"_ - well, what happened when you tried it? ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mmap() device memory into user space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298147/mmap-device-memory-into-user-space), specifics depend on the device which you have not specified.  Of course it is possible for generic memory.  Real device registers may need special care depending on their properties.

Comment: @Notlikethat when I tried mmap it worked.. I am thinking whether it is safe to do fd=open(/dev/mem,O_RDWR) Or Is it better if we write one char driver /dev/my_mem for mapping my device register set region instead of /dev/mem which works on entire memory.